# AngularJS filling table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to create a table with the following object:

```
        this.customer =
    [{
        cid:"1",
        productid:"1",
        src:"walmart",
        total:"1"
    },
    {
        cid:"1",
        productid:"1",
        src:"target",
        total:"2"
    },
    {
        cid:"1",
        productid:"1",
        src:"tjmax",
        total:"2"
    },
    {
        cid:"1",
        productid:"2",
        src:"walmart",
        total:"1"
    },
    {
        cid:"1",
        productid:"2",
        src:"target",
        total:"4"
    },
    {
        cid:"1",
        productid:"2",
        src:"tjmax",
        total:"0"
    },
   {
        cid:"2",
        productid:"1",
        src:"walmart",
        total:"0"
    },
    {
        cid:"2",
        productid:"1",
        src:"target",
        total:"3"
    },
    {
        cid:"2",
        productid:"1",
        src:"tjmax",
        total:"6"
    },
{
        cid:"2",
        productid:"2",
        src:"walmart",
        total:"4"
    },
    {
        cid:"2",
        productid:"2",
        src:"target",
        total:"6"
    },
    {
        cid:"2",
        productid:"2",
        src:"tjmax",
        total:"8"
    }];
```

I need to build a table utilizing AngulaJS and Bootstrap; with bootstrap I don't have any problem. I'm trying to use ng-repeat but I'm not getting the result I want. Here is the way I want my table.

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| cid | productId1       | productId2       |
+-----+------------------+------------------+
| 1   | wal:1,tar:2,tj:2 | wal:1,tar:4,tj:0 |
+-------------------------------------------+
| 2   | wal:0,tar:3,tj:6 | wal:4,tar:6,tj:8 |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Can I achieve this with ng-repeat? Any ideas utilizing other directives?

### Update 1 SEP 2016

Building this app I create a js object to simulate the json I will bet from a web service. After I got help here, I was able to finish my html. I fired up the web service to get the real data. Now the table is not getting filled with data. I opened dev tools to check for errors and I have 0 error. I also checked `Network` and `Responses` and the json object is coming through, so I have no problems with my web service. What might be wrong? Here is my `$http` code.

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var app =   angular.module('myApp', ['angular.filter']);
// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
app.controller('CustomerTable', function ($scope, $http) {

    // GET request example:
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '../_includes/web_service_person.php'
    }).then(function successCallback(data) {
        $scope.customer = data;
    }, function errorCallback(data) {
        console.log(":(");
    });
});

})();
```

I also `<pre>{{customer | json}}<?pre>` and I can see the json object coming through. All I'm getting in my table is **undefined**. How can I get my data in the table?

Comment: i would pre-process my data to prepare the view stage. The problem here is that you'r fina lstructure is totally different from your source. You need to compute it somewhat

Comment: column header is dynamic or fixed ?

Comment: Either if you try to object make as group wise then bind data in angular to easily you can do it

Comment: Type `console.log` in your `successCallback` callback. Like this `console.log(data)`.

Comment: Successful, my object is there.

Comment: `Object {data: Array[50], status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}`

Comment: I also debug my code including `<pre>{{customer | json }}</pre>` and I pull the data is successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To construct this table we need to group and filter `customer` array.

To facilitate the task, you can use [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter).

Example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/wwbqpab0/).

```js
angular.module("ExampleApp", ['angular.filter'])
  .controller("ExampleController", function($scope) {
    $scope.customer = [{
      cid: "1",
      productid: "1",
      src: "walmart",
      total: "1"
    }, {
      cid: "1",
      productid: "1",
      src: "target",
      total: "2"
    }, {
      cid: "1",
      productid: "1",
      src: "tjmax",
      total: "2"
    }, {
      cid: "1",
      productid: "2",
      src: "walmart",
      total: "1"
    }, {
      cid: "1",
      productid: "2",
      src: "target",
      total: "4"
    }, {
      cid: "1",
      productid: "2",
      src: "tjmax",
      total: "0"
    }, {
      cid: "2",
      productid: "1",
      src: "walmart",
      total: "0"
    }, {
      cid: "2",
      productid: "1",
      src: "target",
      total: "3"
    }, {
      cid: "2",
      productid: "1",
      src: "tjmax",
      total: "6"
    }, {
      cid: "2",
      productid: "2",
      src: "walmart",
      total: "4"
    }, {
      cid: "2",
      productid: "2",
      src: "target",
      total: "6"
    }, {
      cid: "2",
      productid: "2",
      src: "tjmax",
      total: "8"
    }];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.11/angular-filter.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>cid</th>
      <th ng-repeat="(product, value) in customer|groupBy:'productid'">productid{{product}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="(cid, value) in customer|groupBy:'cid'">
      <td>{{cid}}</td>
      <td ng-repeat="(product, value) in customer|groupBy:'productid'">
        <span ng-repeat="item in value|filterBy:['cid']:cid">
          {{item.src}}:{{item.total}},
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see the angular-filter listed in [angularjs 1.4.8](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/). Either I see a [angularjs 0.5.11](https://code.angularjs.org). I'm actually using [angularjs 1.5.8](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/) and I don't see angular-filter either. Even though I see that is working here, when I load the `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.11/angular-filter.js"></script>` is not working for me. I also `alt`+`command`+`i` to pull the dev tools and I don't have errors loading library.

Comment: Got angular-filter from the link you provide. I overlooked the link before.

Comment: I had my object with `this.customer`. I changed it to `$scope.customer` and now is working.

Comment: Maybe, you are using `controller as` syntax in `ng-controller`.

Comment: In this question I built that js object to build the html. The reality is that the data is coming from a json that is served by a php web service. After I built the entire html with the css, now the angular code is not working. my `$http` looks like this.  `$http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '../_includes/web_service_person.php'
        }).then(function successCallback(data) {
            $scope.customer = data;
        }, function errorCallback(data) {
            console.log(":(");
        });`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>  cid </th>
    <th>  productId1 </th>
    <th>  productId2 </th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="customer">
      <td>{{customer.cid }}</td>
      <td>{{customer.productId1 }}</td>
      <td>{{customer.productId2 }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @ojuskulkarni - No, I was just saying that you have posted an angular view (not ng-view directive), which Singh is asking for

Answer (score 0):

#### This is an update of my own question.

After doing some research for several days I tweaked the `$http` code to solve my problem. The code is the following:

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'path'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.customer = response.data;
        console.log(response.data);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(":(");
    });
```

Thanks to  @Stepan Kasyanenko I got the data in the table the way was required. Thanks to Peter, a friend of mine, that helped with the web service.